# Can not understand simplification of equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

Hello,

in the picture there is an equation I can not understand. What I do not understand is how to get to the first step. I have been thinking and thinking but can not find an explanation. Could somebody please explain? Thanks.

Comment: Note that $(-\frac{1}{x}+1) = 1 - \frac{1}{x} = \frac{x}{x}-\frac{1}{x} = \frac{x-1}{x}$.  The first equality is just be rearranging.  The second equality by replacing $1$ by $\frac{x}{x}$ as anything divided by itself is equal to $1$ (*so long as it is nonzero, but we are requiring that already if we are talking about $\frac{1}{x}$ in the first place*).  The final equality here is just combining fractions who have the same denominator.  With practice, these manipulations can possibly be done in your head and are unnecessary to write individually.

Comment: Note also that there should be a proviso for the last step: for $x\not=1.$

Comment: @AdrianKeister as well as $x\neq 0$.

Comment: @AndrewChin: Quite right. It's obvious from the original expression that $0$ and $1$ are not in the domain, but it's not obvious at the end.

Comment: Could maybe somebody explain how x(x-1)/(x-1) equates into x?

Answer (score 1):

Applying the distributive property of multiplication, we have
\begin{align}
(-\frac1x+1)\color{blue}{\bigg(\frac{x^2}{x-1}\bigg)}&=-\frac1x\color{blue}{\bigg(\frac{x^2}{x-1}\bigg)}+1\color{blue}{\bigg(\frac{x^2}{x-1}\bigg)}\\\
&=\frac{-x^2}{x(x-1)}+\frac{x^2}{x-1}\color{red}{\cdot\frac{x}{x}}\\
&=\frac{-x^2+x^3}{x(x-1)}\\&=\frac{x^2(x-1)}{x(x-1)}\\
&=x
\end{align}

The complete simplification is $\boxed{x, x\neq0,1}$.

Answer (score 0):

They reduce the first factor to the same denominator, writing
$\;1-\dfrac1 x=\dfrac{x-1}x$, then expand, multiplying the numerators and the denominators.

In my opinion, it is much too long. Here is how I would do it:
$$\Bigl(1-\frac1 x\Bigr)\frac{x^2}{x-1}=\frac{x-1}{\not x}\frac{x^{\not2}}{x-1}=x.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\require{cancel}$
We bagin by expanding the LHS
\begin{align*}
&\left(-\frac{1}{x}+1\right)\left(\frac{x^2}{x-1}\right)
\\ \\
=&\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right) \left(\frac{x\cdot x}{x-1}\right)
\\ \\\
=&\left(\frac{x\cdot \cancel{x(x-1}}{\cancel{x(x-1)}}\right)
=x
\end{align*}