# Understanding the simplification $\frac{x(x-1)}{x-1} = x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

May somebody explain why this expression results into "$x$"?

$$\frac{x(x-1)}{x-1} = x$$
[original question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8WgM.jpg)

---

Note: This is the final simplification in the problem described [in my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3404733/409).

Comment: Divide top and bottom by $x-1$

Comment: You've asked the same question not even an hour ago and you've gotten a lot of responses. I'm doubting you can't understand any of those answers.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Rather than posting a separate question about the same problem as [your previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3404733/can-not-understand-simplification-of-equation), you could/should simply have commented on one of the answers to ask for clarification of the last bit of simplification. ... That said, since people have begun posting answers here, you might as well leave this question as-is.

Comment: @ J.W. Tanner why divide it by top and bottom, whats the rule here?

Comment: If $a\ne0$ then $\dfrac a a = 1$.  Now take $a=x-1$

Answer (score 1):

As functions they're actually not quite the same.  The function $g(x)=x$ is defined everywhere, whereas $f(x)=\frac{x(x-1)}{x-1}$ is not defined at $x=1$.  However, the two functions are equal where $f(x)$ is defined (as you can see by cancelling the common factor of $x-1$ from the numerator and denominator) and $g(x)$ can be viewed as a continuous extension of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

your equation is simply $$\frac {x(x-1)}{(x-1)}$$ the parentheses in the denominator do not change the equation

Therefore, you can simply divide the numerator by the denominator

Answer (score 0):

Tanner answered correctly. I must add, though, that what he said is only true if and only if $x \neq 1$. That way, you avoid the much dreaded division by zero.

Comment: If $x=1$ then $\dfrac {x-1}{x-1} $ is not defined